# slideshow not working; works locally but not when uploaded

Tags: html, css

As the title suggests, the slideshow works locally but not when it's uploaded to the server.All pictures are in the correct location for images to show.
Does anyone have any idea or reason for why it is not working?
Any help is appreciated. Thanks. 
 The slideshow code is:

```
    <div class="clr"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="outerbox">
        <div id="sliderbox">
           <img src="Images/b.jpg">
            <img src="Images/b1.jpg">
            <img src="Images/b2.jpg">
            <img src="Images/b3.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>

/*slider code*/

#outerbox
{
    margin: 0px;
  width: 1300px;
    overflow: hidden;

}
#sliderbox
 {
    position:relative;
    margin-left: 25px;
    width:5200px;
    animation-name: anupam;
    animation-duration: 10s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;

}
#sliderbox img 
{
    float: left;
}
@keyframes anupam {
    0%
    {
        left:0px;
    }
    20%
    {
        left:0px;
    }
    25%
    {
        left:-1300px;
    }
    45%
    {
        left: -1300px;
    }
    50%
    {
       left: -2600px; 
    }
    70%
    {
        left: -2600px;
    }
    75%
    {
        left:-3900px;
    }
    95%
    {
        left: -3900px;
    }
    100%
    {
        left:-3900px; 
    }
```

All pictures are in the correct location for images to show.

Does anyone have any idea or reason for why it is not working?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a working/not working link we can see?

Answer (score 0):

Did you checked folder's name?
"Images" not same "images" for Linux servers.